# Obtener ficheros modificados hace más de 20 minutos en shell ksh versión 88

Tags: script, ksh

Necesito encontrar los ficheros modificados hace más de 20 minutos.
Lo hago en una máquina con Solaris y la shell ksh.
He probado con find -mmin y no funciona, así que he pasado a una variable los minutos de la hora de la última modificación del archivo.
El script que he creado para este fin es éste (las líneas comentadas dan error):

```
#!/bin/ksh

horaComplModfArchivo=`ls -lrt /ficherosEnviados.log|awk '{print $8}'`

# ficherosMas20=`find -mmin +20´
# typeset -i ficherosMas20
# integer minModfArchivo=`echo $horaComplModfArchivo | cut -c1-2`

minModfArchivo=`echo $horaComplModfArchivo | cut -c4-5`

echo El minuto de la última modificación del archivo es $minModfArchivo > $dirLogTrust/ficheroDePruebas.log

echo La última modificación del archivo /ficherosEnviados.log se produjo a las $horaComplModfArchivo h >> $dirLogTrust/ficheroDePruebas.log

if ( $minModfArchivo -le 20 )
then
    echo El minuto del archivo modificado es menor o igual a 20 >> $dirLogTrust/ficheroDePruebas.log
else
    echo El minuto del archivo modificado es mayor a 20 >> $dirLogTrust/ficheroDePruebas.log
fi
```

Cuando comento la parte del if y ejecuto el archivo, el log resultante dice:

```
El minuto de la última modificación del archivo es 49
La última modificación del archivo /ficherosEnviados.log se produjo a las 10:49 h
```

Si dejo sin comentar el if y ejecuto el archivo, no se crea el log y la consola imprime:

```
compruebaEnvioCada20MinPrueba2.sh: 49: not found
```

Cuando ejecuto en la consola de putty este comando:

```
what /bin/ksh
```

obtengo ésto:

```
/bin/ksh:
        Version M-11/16/88i
        SunOS 5.8 Generic 110662-21 Aug 2005
```

Parece que los minutos se guardan como texto, y no como integer, pero no consigo pasarlo a integer.

¿Podría alguien ayudarme, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Lo he podido resolver sustituyendo:

```
if ( $minModfArchivo -le 20 )
```

por

```
if test $minModfArchivo -le 20
```

También funciona:

```
if [ $minModfArchivo -le 20 ]
```